# Django import export: Error encountered while trying to read file CSV

Tags: django, django-import-export

Hi I have a problem with django import export,

```
Django==1.8
django-import-export==1.1.0
```

When I want to import a small csv (1 line) I have directly a blank page with the message

> Error encountered while trying to read file: XXX.csv

I see in the network console a POST to http://localhost:8001/admin/XXX/XXX/import/
with a 200 response with this message.

It is the same behavior whatever the model.

Comment: I fixed it with https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/957#issuecomment-496609753

Comment: @ralph write that as the solution. You 100% deserve this internet points... was wondering WTF was going wrong. thanks for finding the fix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to downgrade tablib to 0.12.1

Add to requirements:

```
tablib==0.12.1
```

See my fix https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/957#issuecomment-496609753